# MATLAB - Sort 2D points ensuring adjacent points differ by one coordinate?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a series of points whose coordinates are as follows

```
pts_x = 3   4   5   6   7   8   2   3   8   9   2   9   2   9   2   9   2   9   2   3   8   9   3   4   5   6   7   8
pts_y = 2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   7   7   8   8   8   8   9   9   9   9   9   9
```

If I directly connect them following the current order, I get

[image]

But actually, I need a polygon. In order to re-ordere the points so that connecting them gives me a closed polygon, I come up with a solution that sorts the points in such a way that **only one** of `x` and `y` coordinates differs between two adjacent points.

How should I do this? I am in MATLAB.

Comment: Related: [Sorting clockwise polygon points in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935324/sorting-clockwise-polygon-points-in-matlab)

Comment: @LuisMendo: good find. Closing as duplicate.